# Может ли в Linux статическая библиотека использовать динамическую?

Tags: linux, c, so

Пытаюсь сделать приложение и статическую библиотеку, которая использует ffmpeg. Фрагмент CMakeLists.txt для статической библиотеки:

```
find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

add_library(prj STATIC ${SOURCE_LIB})
target_include_directories(prj  PRIVATE ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(prj  ${AVCODEC_LIBRARY} ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARY} ${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY})
```

Всё собирается, nm показывает нужные мне функции:

```
U avformat_close_input
U avformat_find_stream_info
U avformat_free_context
U avformat_network_init
```

В CMakeLists.txt приложения:

```
add_library( libprj STATIC IMPORTED )
set_property( TARGET libprj PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /tmp/libprj.a )
add_executable(app ${SOURCE_EXE})
target_link_libraries(app libprj)
```

При сборке приложения множество сообщений о статической библиотеке, типа

```
ошибка: /tmp/libprj.a(prj.c.o): in function `st':
ошибка: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input'
```

Задумался. А так, вообще, можно делать? Или, искать ошибку в конфиге сборки?

Comment: а кто ей мешает? другое дело, как заставить cmake это собрать

Comment: Не. Попробовал вообще без cmake, просто gcc. Проблема осталась.

Comment: похоже, что библиотеку  ffmpeg не добавили. Или добавили, но после Вашей статической

Answer (score 1):

Статические библиотеки представляют собой архив из собранных объектных файлов. Шаг линковки для них не выполняется. Он и не может выполняться, так как не известно, какие символы будут использоваться - это становится известно после того, как библиотека прилинкуется к бинарю. Соответственно и динамические библиотеки необходимо линковать к конечному бинарю. Причем на линукс есть проблема с порядком линковки - библиотеки, которые содержат недостающие символы, должны линковаться строго после единиц трансляции и библиотек, использующих эти символы.

Answer (score -1):

В общем, абсолютно чёткого понимания нет, но есть предположение. Если указать библиотеки ffmpeg при компоновке приложения, то всё нормально. Похоже на то, что, таки, статически прилинкованная библиотека никак не участвует в подгрузке динамической, просто ссылаясь на функции из неё. Собственно, учитывая, что статическая библиотека становится частью приложения, то, в принципе, логично, что именно оно и ответственнено за загрузку нужных .so.

Comment: я даже не думал, что до такого дойдет. Собственно динамически подлинкованные библиотеки подгружает загрузчик elf файлов. И если ему не указать, что именно нужно грузить, то он и не сможет загрузить. Линковщик же должен составить инструкции ему.

Comment: а dlopen не то?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том, что библиотечные файлы ffmpeg реализованы средствами компилятора C, а не C++, а значит, в них отсутствует mangling. Отсюда и проблема поиска сигнатур C++ там где этих сигнатур нет.

Чтобы решить эту проблему достаточно включение заголовков ffmpeg, в коде программы, заключить в extern "C" {  }.